# Problems with contenteditable div in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, contenteditable

I am using a div with the contenteditable attribute in Firefox, the text I write goes outside the div, although it works correctly in chrome, I have a problem in firefox, is it because of the browser or in my code?

html;

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-duyuru" id="inputGroup-sizing-default" style="font-weight: 500;">Announcement Type:</span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-duyuru" name="dduyurutipi" id="dduyurutipi" aria-label="With textarea" contenteditable="true">UNPLANNED</div>
</div>
```

> **Firefox ;**
> [image]

> **Chrome;**
> [image]

Comment: good good, nicely done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting

```
word-break: break-all;
```

or

```
word-break: break-word;
```

Comment: word-break: break-all;works for me thank u